# IDispatchOperationSelector.SelectOperation not called

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to implement `IDispatchOperationSelector` to invoke a different service class methodthan the one specified in `SOAPAction`, but `SelectOperation` is not getting called, unless there's a method in the service interface which is already matching `SOAPAction` in the request.

Here's a minimum service reproducing my issue:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Invoke(string input);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public string Invoke(string input)
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

This is my `IDispatchOperationSelector` implementation:

```
public class OperationSelector : IDispatchOperationSelector
{
    public string SelectOperation(ref Message message)
    {
        return "Invoke";
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm applying it to my endpoint:

```
public class EndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    { }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
        BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    { }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, 
        EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.OperationSelector = new OperationSelector();
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    { }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), 
        new Uri("http://localhost:8000/Service.svc"));
    var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
    endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new EndpointBehavior());
    host.Open();

    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
}
```

With the following request `SelectOperation` is called:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/Service.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService/Invoke"
Host: localhost:8000
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 158

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><Invoke xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><input>Test</input></Invoke></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

As soon as I change `SOAPAction` in the request to a different value (e.g. `"http://tempuri.org/IService/Invoke1"`), `SelectOperation` isn't called any more and the service responds:

> The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IService/Invoke1' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

If I add another operation to the service interface with `Action="*"`, then `SelectOperation` is called for any `SOAPAction` value:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*")]
void UnrecognizedMessageHandler(Message msg);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it really a requirement for a service to have such a fallback method declared to be able to use `IDispatchOperationSelector`?